# How to receive error description of invalid REST call in required language?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

If my REST call to SharePoint server is invalid it returns error information with code and description, but always for `xml:lang="en-US"` language.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">You must fill out all required properties before checking in this document.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Is it possible to set required language for error's description?

P.S.: As I see it completely ignores "Accept-Language" header in my request.

Comment: It's essential for me. Because SP list of errors is huge and not well-know, translate all of them manually is not variant for me.